# Is it possible to use a generic that extends a class with a generic in it?

Tags: java, http, generics

An example of this is:
`SBHttpRequest<D  extends SBHttpDeserializer<?>, RBT>` : this compiles fine but the type is not bounded for the response class

`SBHttpRequest<D  extends SBHttpDeserializer<RT>, RBT>` : This does not compile: RT cannot resolved to a type

I also tried `SBHttpRequest<D<RT>  extends SBHttpDeserializer<RT>, RBT>`: which it tells me
the < > are in the wrong spots

D is the deserializer class which extends SBHttpDesrializer
RT is the response type or  the type the deserializer changes the response into
RBT is the request body type (always a byte[] in this instance)

I would like to use the response type for bounding some conditions in the class and clear some raw type compiler warnings.

Comment: "*I also tried `SBHttpRequest<D<RT>  extends SBHttpDeserializer<RT>, RBT>`*" - Add `RT` as generic parameter: `SBHttpRequest<RT, D<RT> extends SBHttpDeserializer<RT>, RBT>`

Comment: The only problem with that solution is it will require the other projects using to add the response type, but it may be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Either add a generic type parameter for the return type, or create a class/interface when your want to lock down the type:

```
class ByteArraySBHttpDeserializer implements SBHttpDeserializer<byte[]> {}
```

Then:

```
SBHttpRequest< ByteArraySBHttpDeserializer, RBT>
```

It’s a bit clunky, but so is generics.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with Turing85's idea.

Just include the type

Despite sonarlint's complaint about generic names being larger than 1 character:
`public class SBHttpRequest<RESPONSE_TYPE, DESRERIALIZER_TYPE extends SBHttpDeserializer<RESPONSE_TYPE>, REQUEST_BODY_TYPE>`